# How to save information in multiple text boxes with save and load buttons

Tags: java, android, textbox, persistence

I'm trying to create a simple Android program that has text boxes for name, address, phone number, etc. When the user puts this information in and hits save it clears the text boxes, and when they hit the load button it retrieves the info. I know how to do it with one EditText box, but I can't figure out multiple. Can I do this inside one try/catch statement, or do I need more than one? This is what I have right now:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private EditText textBoxName;
    private EditText textBoxAddress;
    private EditText textBoxCity;
    private EditText textBoxPhone;
    private EditText textBoxEmail;
    private static final int READ_BLOCK_SIZE = 100;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textBoxName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtName);
        textBoxAddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtAddress);
        textBoxCity = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtCity);
        textBoxPhone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPhone);
        textBoxEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtEmail);
        Button saveBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
        Button loadBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLoad);

        saveBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String strName = textBoxName.getText().toString();
                String strAddress = textBoxAddress.getText().toString();
                String strCity = textBoxCity.getText().toString();
                String strPhone = textBoxPhone.getText().toString();
                String strEmail = textBoxEmail.getText().toString();
                try {
                    FileOutputStream fOut = openFileOutput("textfile.txt", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);

                    OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);

                    //write the string to the file

                    osw.write(strName);

                    osw.flush();

                    osw.close();

                    //display file saved messages
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "File saved successfully!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    //clears the EditText
                    textBoxName.setText("");
                    textBoxAddress.setText("");
                    textBoxCity.setText("");
                    textBoxPhone.setText("");
                    textBoxEmail.setText("");
                }
                catch (IOException ioe)
                {
                    ioe.printStackTrace();
                }


            }
        });

        loadBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try
                {
                    FileInputStream fIn = openFileInput("textfile.txt");
                    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fIn);

                    char[] inputBuffer = new char[READ_BLOCK_SIZE];
                    String s = "";

                    int charRead;
                    while ((charRead = isr.read(inputBuffer))>0)
                    {
                        //convert the chars to a String
                        String readString = String.copyValueOf(inputBuffer, 0, charRead);
                        s += readString;

                        inputBuffer = new char[READ_BLOCK_SIZE];
                    }
                    //set the EditText to the text that has been read
                    textBoxName.setText(s);
                    textBoxAddress.setText(s);
                    textBoxCity.setText(s);
                    textBoxPhone.setText(s);
                    textBoxEmail.setText(s);

                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "File loaded successfully!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                catch (IOException ioe)
                {
                    ioe.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Shared Preferences to store and retrieve information in Android.

Answer (score 0):

you can use shared preferences for this purpose . Just put the value into shared preference and load when the user need this info like username and password saved locally into any login form.